# Is there a simple way to change the toolbar from Full to Summary in LVWP?

Tags: list-view-web-part

I am on this since 6am this morning. Over 13 hours. Still issues. Can anyone suggest a different way to changing the Toolbar to Summary Toolbar? I would appreciate it.

Is there a simple way to change the toolbar from Full to Summary in List View Web Part using object model? I already have object model that adds lvwp. I dont want to re-invent the wheel. By default it's giving "Full Toolbar" and it's good for some wp. However, I have some special WPs that need "Summary Toolbar". I tried few suggested by various blogs but none is helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally called MS support and they wanted me to [try this link](http://www.sharepointstudio.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=17) and boom. It worked first try.

Comment: Where in the link that you provided does it mention the toolbar or summary?  I followed the link and was not able to find any of that information.  Could you please provide some code in your answer?

Comment: same as skeletank. Did not find anything on that link... Useless...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit easy to point you to a website, but I really think this is what you are looking for: Changing the toolpart of a ListViewWebPart...
http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=70640fe5-28d9-464f-b1c9-91e07c8f7e47&ID=90

Comment: It's never hitting inside this line  if (toolbarNode != null) so I am assuming toolbarnode is not null. well, how to set to Summary toolbar (aka freeform) when it's null?

Comment: Okay. I have debugged again and again and stuck with this issue for past 5 hours. Can anyone direct me to right path? Thanks